# Android Facebook SDK 3.5 request works only with both "Bundle" and on "graphPath" param

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

It's my fist post here, so please, go easy :)

I'm integrating Facebook SDK in an Android application. After the user logs in, I want to show him the app's last post in facebook, so I'm triYng to get it with(as graph object):

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putInt("limit", 1);

Request request = new Request(session, inRequestId + "/posts/?limit=1&access_token=" +
session.getAccessToken().toString(), params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        if(response != null){
            if(response.getError() != null)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error retrieveng last post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
                updateFacebookView( response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject() );
        }
    }
    }
});
request.executeAsync();
```

This works, fine I think, but if I'm triyng to make it without graphPath's limit=1 parameter (inRequestId + "/posts/?access_token=" + session.getAccessToken().toString()), it has no limit, and if I don't put bundle param "limit", (as string or as int tested), it gives me this error:

```
09-30 17:51:47.094: E/caca(19703): {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, errorType: 
OAuthException, errorMessage: Malformed access token
CAAT76i2gxTgBAKyLzc8SI6y7V1pGJ0fmbLWCtuKdhHIEZAQBA0jYx4YqZB8IgRDJMUlw1XrvZCLJ8kxKdZCRG3LNbrVL8fB34ZBlyvlqadT192MCWMkst1lMSdFwtRVPWiSNfBfi8Gq2RHZCWskrBVTjAwPDKyDMGLSU8sPnXfe0r2tsZBdZCXLCOJGQtE76sJkr7n8SdOU4j1KopkvT0Mux7QBGf7ZBXtCRqDnsZAZCxSNHAZDZD?access_token=CAAT76i2gxTgBAKyLzc8SI6y7V1pGJ0fmbLWCtuKdhHIEZAQBA0jYx4YqZB8IgRDJMUlw1XrvZCLJ8kxKdZCRG3LNbrVL8fB34ZBlyvlqadT192MCWMkst1lMSdFwtRVPWiSNfBfi8Gq2RHZCWskrBVTjAwPDKyDMGLSU8sPnXfe0r2tsZBdZCXLCOJGQtE76sJkr7n8SdOU4j1KopkvT0Mux7QBGf7ZBXtCRqDnsZAZCxSNHAZDZD}
```

Am I not using this correctly or it's a bug? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter for the constructor is the "path" of the request, but you're also putting request parameters into the path, which messes with the other parameters the Request class may try to put on your behalf. A couple of things to do:

1. Don't put request parameters in the path parameter, stick them into the "params" bundle.
2. Don't put the access token (the Request class automatically gets it from the session object).

Try something like this:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putInt("limit", 1);

Request request = new Request(session, inRequestId + "/posts", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
    ...
});
request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. I already got it yesterday! Thanks